# Finding short-circuit across 3.3V power rail and ground rail on PCB

Tags: pcb-design

I have a short-circuit between my 3.3V and ground power rail on my assembled PCB. How do I find where the short is?

Should I start by removing components one-by-one from the board?

Comment: Start at the output and trace back through the circuit checking the voltage across each device for a voltage drop or if not the device is shorted.

Comment: @SamR., your saying to measure the voltage to each components, if no drop of voltage means, it is short?

Comment: If there is no drop in voltage across the device it is shorted.

Comment: @SamR I think the OP is saying something is shorted across his power rails so all components across the power rails would measure shorted. So measuring votlage drops does not help because they all measure the same thing.

Comment: Board has so many components like passive and active, if there is short of 3.3V and ground in one section, difficult to find failure component in that board, because board has so many sections.

Answer (score 2):

First, verify on a blank board that it is not actually the board itself (make it a habit to measure the resistance between ground and power rail on every new PCB layout for this BEFORE you start soldering, especially if you don't have extra blanks to test after you finish soldering).

The second step I usually do is is visually check all the decoupling capacitors since they usually are the majority components connecting the power and ground rails.  The caps are usually big enough that you can see if there is a bridge on them.

The third and last step before I start getting desperate is to look at all adjacent ground and power pins under an eye loupe for a solder bridge or a misaligned pin that touches both ground and power trace.

If you still can't find anything it starts to become a crap shoot. Rather than removing components, it is usually easier to just reflux and remelt all the fine-pitched solder pins in situ (by dragging your solder iron across all the pins via the drag soldering method) and hope you accidentally fix the short.

A desperate measure I sometimes take is I run a high current through the board and look at it under a thermal camera (or slowly scan the board with an IR gun) and hope that enough detectable heat is produced where the short occurs. If I really want to remove components, I start with the decoupling capacitors in case one of them failed short, but removing components is an absolute last resort.

You might skip looking for a solder bridge if you know the short is because a component failed during operation rather than a bad soldering job.

You might want to make it a habit to measure the resistance between your power rails and ground every few components you solder so you can fix things as soon as it happens and you won't have to try and find a needle in a haystack.

Comment: A cheap trick is to put some isopropyl alcohol on the board while it is powered. The areas where the alcohol is evaporating the fastest indicate the area where there is the most heat.

FLIRs work as well, but I've never had the fortune of owning a nice one.

Comment: Wouldn't the alcohol produce its own short though? Due to dissolved contaminants on the board? It would have to be an extremely clean board for the alcohol to stay non-conductive. I think you can use cold spray and watch where the frost melts too quickly, but I've never tried it.

Comment: I should also say that the reason the FLIR is a desperate measure and not the go-to is that, other than the obvious potential heat damage to the board, the FLIR doesn't actually make hot spots as easy to find as your imagination might lead you to believe. Partly due to the fact that you need a suprisingly high resolution FLIR camera and a lot of heat to track small hot spots. Components won't have a perfectly glowing red outline under the camera especially at lower temperature differentials since heat will spill everywhere and greatly blur outlines, if there are even any hot spots that appear.

Comment: If you have a FLIR camera, it shouldn't be reserved for desperate measures.  My experience with a modest FLIR camera was pretty good.  [This image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46038819@N07/38552465490/in/dateposted-public/), for example.  Thermal cameras don't replace imagination.  They supplement it.

Comment: I agree with Toor, the most difficult shorts are copper/solder and are 10s of milliohms or maybe less. I worked for a large company with lots of resources and we could rarely find these types of shorts with FLIRs, liquid crystals, or any other type of thermal method.

Comment: Measuring resistance as suggested by other answers should be included and this a good answer. 

If the fault is on the PCB itself, a quick and destructive way (does not work if the short that has a greater area than the traces) it to apply huge current and see what burns/explodes on an unpopulated PCB. (Could also be used if the original PCB is populated but other than the affected components can be affected. 
It also helps relieve some anger if you have been staring at the PCB for a long time with out finding the short.

Comment: @Morten What would measuring resistance do on a populated board? It only helps on a blank board to check whether the problem is the board itself.

Comment: @Toor It is the same principle as on the unpopulated board as you still have the short. The principle is that the further away from the short you get the higher the resistance, what you are effectively measuring is the resistance in the tracks. You will need a good multimeter. 
Take a look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQetHzNiNJ0

Comment: @Toor as you said, we can take the IR gun and we can find the heat in the LDO, because LDO only produce the 3.3V, in that case, difficult to find the failure component

Answer (score 2):

> I have a short-circuit between my 3.3V and ground power rail on my assembled PCB.
>   How do I find where the short is?

See below.

> Should I start by removing components one-by-one from the board?

No!!! This should not be necessary. See below.

**Summary:** Voltage drop along track sections will lead you to a fault. It helps if I_fault is >> I_no-fault.

**Detail:**

A very useful "trick" is to use a voltmeter set to the most sensitive range available (and sometimes a very low current range may serve the same purpose) to determine where current is flowing by measuring voltage drop along tracks.

Imagine a track A-B-C-D with V+ applied at A and various components and other tracks comnnected to it. Imagine that the short is on a sub circuit connecting to ABCD at point C.
The sub circuit is C-E-F-G with short circuit at point F.

Measuring voltage on ABCD from A to D gives a voltage drop due to current flow along the track.  With the fault current leaving at C, V_A-B and V_B-C will be similar and positive.  BUT V_C-D will be much smaller as the fault current will not be in the C-D section.

In this case the direction of current flow is clear, but if a random section of track X-Y is tested, if V_X-Y is positive then current is flowing from X to Y and if V_X-Y is negative current is flowing from Y to X.

In this case the short circuit has been localised to sub circuit CEFG.
As above V_C-E and V_E-F will be similar but V_F-G will be much smaller as fault current is not flowing in FG.

If the fault is to ground, as it is in this case, the measuring from various points to ground will give decreasing voltages as the fault is approached physically.

Once the general method is understood logical extensions can easily be derived.

Comment: this works!, good description. I used this technique for 25+ years where I was employed, I published an internal paper describing the technique. I was hesitant to reveal it because my company may consider it to be a trade secret. I don't think it is, your post confirms it. I generally needed a voltmeter with 1/100 mV resolution to be successful, but with the proper meter, I was almost always successful in narrowing it down to the exact spot. It helps to inject the current with separate wires, don't share your injection connections with your measurement connections.

Comment: Does this method actually work if there are ground and power planes? I've never had tracks to actually trace voltage drops along along. The short has always been hidden inside an enormous plane.

Comment: @Toor - Yes, planes will have tiny voltage drops. All of the boards I used this technique on had ground and power planes. After you have taken a bunch of measurements, if you can visualize the equipotential lines, it is helpful. Slight temperature changes can cause the readings to drift, you may need to repeat measurements several times.

Comment: @Toor 1. See Mattman944's comment above 2. Sufficient to the morrow is the evil thereof / Horses for courses / If the cap fits / ... :-) -> sometimes yes, sometimes no. Possibly more yes than no. If your design is optimised to hide the fault then it may be of some but limited use. In many cases I'd expect there to be varying voltages that gave a directional guide where to look / in which direction to move. | I've never used the 'burn it down' method on complex boards - but Olin reports having done so - at HP AFAIR :-).

Answer (score 0):

Copper foil of the default thickness (1 ounce/square foot, 1.4 mils or 35 micron thick)
has resistance of 0.000500 (500 microOhms).

1 amp thru that square of copper (for example, a trace 1mm by 1mm) causes 500 microVolts drop. Two squares, at 1 amp, is a millivolt. Some DVMs will easily display that small a voltage, accurately.